# Debian upgrade x11-common error

Tags: debian, upgrade, updates, xorg, apt-get

I upgraded my Debian but I'm getting an error. How can I go around this problem?

```
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up x11-common (1:7.6+8~bpo60+1) ...
Template parse error near `Choices-sr@latin.UTF-8: Samo glavni korisnik, Samo za korisnike konzole, Svako', in stanza #1 of /var/lib/dpkg/info/x11-common.templates
dpkg: error processing x11-common (--configure):
 subprocess post-installation script returned error exit status 9
Errors were encountered while processing:
 x11-common
```

Oh, and I forget to add, I'm a linux newbie so be soft on me :].

Comment: Is your installation configured with a non-English language?

Comment: Well, I guess so. I did not actually configure anything but I guess that it is possible. However, it is definitely not in Serbian as the error suggests

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the templates file has the correct syntax.

E.g.:

```
Description: Please read and press 'Forward' to continue
 TERMS AND CONDITIONS 
 .
 Your use of the "Service", which includes any content you purchase, subscribe to, sync, upload, download, stream, preview, store, share or otherwise access through the Service 
 .
 bla
 bla

Next_section:name
```

I.e.:

- Each sections has a blank line before it (carriage return)
- Multi-line paragraphs start with a space
- Empty lines are "space-dot"